# How to use specific a GPU device for learning in keras R?

Tags: r, keras, gpu

I have two gpu device GTX 1080ti.
I do work in Rstudio with keras.
So, I want to use specific gpu device to each script.
I have heard for this, some people recommend to use `with(tf$device("/:gpu1")`.
But, I am using R not python.
I can't find the tf function and device funtion.
And another recommendation is to use `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"`.
But, I can not find the os.environ function.

Please help me anybody who can help.
So, please tell me more detail about code for this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: I think `tf$device` is accessible with `library(tensorflow)`. `os.environ` does look like python however.